# Properly dispose QuickTime control

Tags: c#, activex, dispose, quicktime

I'm currently developing an application for Windows platform that will be able to play Quick Time videos.
The targeted OS versions are Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

I successfully used the Apple ActiveX QuickTime Control 2.0 (in C#) and everything works well on Windows XP.

However, on Vista and Windows 7 I'm facing problems with properly disposing the control.
Here are the "steps to reproduce" :
- I create the Quick Time control dynamically at runtime and I place it on a panel;

- I successfully play videos with it;
- At some point I close the application main form; the application windows is destroyed and the application will continue to run in the background (doing operations like syncing videos); at this point the control is disposed using IDisposable pattern; I can't explicitly dispose the Movie object (from the ActiveX control) because I get an exception like: "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."; I just use (AxQTOControlLib.AxQTControl) player.Dispose(); On Windows XP this is fine but not on Vista and 7
- I restore my application (from tool bar where it was running in background) and try to open the video again; At this point an AccessViolationException "Attempted to read/write protected memory" is thrown;

My questions are:

- Why is this happening only on Vista and Windows 7 ?
- On XP is a hidden leak ?
- What is the recommended way to dispose the control (with its movie object) when it is created at runtime ?

I'm now using an explicit Movie.Disconnect() call (although I don't now what this disconnect means because I could not find proper documentation) fallowed by a QuickTimeTerminate() call before the form is closed.
While my method is working it is kind of design breaking so I would like to know a better way of doing this.

Thank you,
Mosu'

Update: 
I just discovered that my method is not workink. I use to players: QuickTime control and Windows Media player control (both ActiveX) and when one fails to play a file the other one is used. I was seeing the output of WindowsMedia player and thinking the methos IS working. 
So my fix is not working at all.

Comment: Yuck, quite a crummy control.  Try hiding your form instead of disposing it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can't do this because all the other controls (including the panel the control sits on) are being disposed. 
The application is in a mature state. I have been asked to added this features. So this is not an option.

Comment: I've got the same issue unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people seem to be having this error.

This page offers an interesting approach: http://www.theusenetarchive.com/usenet-message-how-to-properly-destroy-quicktime-activex-object-10384503.htm

> The crash occurs because of file handles still being open.  I was
>   'unloading' movies from the Quicktime control by wiring a null string
>   to the FileName or URL property.  Quicktime doesn't handle this
>   correctly and leaves the original file open.  So instead I wired
>   a path to an actual image file (Quicktime does images too) that was
>   all black.  Eveything seems fine now.